# Password-Box not showing any content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, webforms

I have a small websolution that needs the user to input a password. I have two input boxes

```
<input type="password" runat="server" id="m_txtPassword1"/>
```

If I set some chars to the Value-property of the control like this:

```
m_txtPassword1.Value="someChars";
```

The password box is rendered empty. No bullets are shown. If I look into the rendered html-source, also no value-tag has been rendered. If I change the type to

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="m_txtPassword1"/>
```

the chars are shown. Is this by design? How can I disable this feature?
Please note, I don't want to put a real password into the value-property, I only want to show the user that there is already a password set, and this is IMO done best with some 8 bullets in the input-control. But for this, I need the possibility to set the value-property of the control.

**Update**

For all, having the same problem: I have tried to declare `<asp:textbox id="m_txtPassword1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />` with the same result. Also `m_txtPassword1.Attributes["value"]="someChars"` has not helped.

It seems that this is realy not possible.

**As a workaround**, I declared the password-boxes as plain html without the runat="server" and have set the value-property in markup (via two properties from the code-behind). Not nice but I really want to show the user that he has already entered a password.
Another workaround would be to set the value through javascript on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by default. You cannot set a password.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I will wait until tomorrow, maybe someone knows about a possibility to disable this feature, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: You could add something with Javascript on the client side. But considering that most browsers autofill password fields, I would not do that. It confuses the user.

Answer (score 1):

I make this works,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertValue()
{
alert(document.getElementById("password1").value);
}
function setpassword()
{
   password1.value="someChars";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="password" id="password1" value="" />
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="alertValue()" value="Show default value" />
<input type="button" id="button2" onclick="setpassword()" value="Set value" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this:
http://jsbin.com/ocexo5

Comment: +1 Thanks, yes it's is similar to the solution I did, look at my workaround. However my question is, if it's possible to do with the MS-controls (runat=server), for not making a hack.

Answer (score 1):

It is by design, for security reasons - so that the password is not in the
HTML in plain text.

Now, you could write out javascript to set the value property of the textbox
on the client, of course this would still mean that you have the password in
plain text in the HTML.

Here is example of the page:

Markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setPwd()
{
    var Pwd = "<%=Pwd %>";
    var txtText = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtText");
    txtText.value = Pwd;
 }
</script>
<input type="password" id="txtText" runat="server"/>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Pwd;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Pwd = "password";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( this.GetType(),"somescript","setPwd();",true); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, yes I thought also to this as a possibility, however I prefer a workaround without client-sided-script, so that all clients will have the same behaviour. But thanks, the solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Textbox11.Attributes.Add("Value",whatever_your_password_is)
```

Comment: This may solve the current problem, but defeats the original purpose. Password controls have no value so that they cannot be read out from the HTML source.